# Trouble linking ChicagoBoss controllers to views

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I'm making a website in Erlang, but I'm having troubles. I installed Chicagoboss and the server starts, but I have a problem. They say to go to this page `localhost:8001/pages/index` when i go to this page I get an error:

> No routes matched the requested URL. (Don't worry, this message will not appear in   production.)

I did not do anything, I coded the file in `src/controllers/main.erl`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you read the pdf:  http://www.chicagoboss.org/tutorial.pdf  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used ChicagoBoss, but this question is extremely basic and you should read carefully tutorial before asking. Take a look how the requested URL is dispatched:

```
host:port/yourcontroller/youraction
```

will invoke function like

> youraction('GET', []) ->
>       {output, "Hello World!"}.

from file src/controller/PROJECT_yourcontroller_controller.erl. This sample works out of the box. In general case look at PROJECT/priv/PROJECT.routes to define rules to bind URL patterns to their controllers actions.